# i cannot run Elementary os

Tags: release-juno, grub, elementary-project, acpi

I realize with my laptop Asus Vivobook pro, I cannot run Elementary OS .

here I write my Laptop specifics:

Intel I7 8750H GTX 1050

Asus Vivobook pro N580GD Bios Version : 313

16 GB of RAM

When i Run Elementary os gives me this error:

ACPI Error (psparse-0537): Method parse/execution failed

i try PCI=noacpi , the system load but i cannot use mouse keyboard etc...
i try to install but after 50% he told me : I cannot install GRUB.

I cannot understand the problem, I prefer LINUX for Work and I really need.

thanks all

Comment: How i solve it :

Answer (score 1):

How I solve it :

I read only my GTX 1050 is not compatible with ubuntu without a driver.

So :

I during boot I click "e" Button and I wrote after quiet splash This :

> nouveau.modeset=0

after that, I install Elementary os as normal.

For the first start-up, I use just put nouveau.modeset=0 on the boot screen

after I went to the software center and I install Nvidia Drivers.

now Elementary os Works fine.